# Does "taking the integral of both sides" of an equation preserve equality?

Tags: integration

Are there any restrictions on when you can and can't take the integral of both sides?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no issue in taking an integral on both sides so long as you know that one side is integrable. If you have $f=g$, then for all intents and purposes they are literally the same object. Therefore, they must have the same integral. It's a bit redundant sounding, but if I integrate a function $f$, it better be equal to its own integral.

Note: this is true provided the equality you are talking about is true over the entire region of integration. If $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x) = x$, then it's true that $f(x) = g(x)$ if $x=1$ or $0$, but in this case we don't have equality over any interval, so in this case
$$
  \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx \neq \int_0^1 g(x) \,dx
$$
even though we had a certain equality. You want to make sure that the "both sides" are equal at *every* point you want to integrate over.